# xterm -e not terminating when script finishes execution

Tags: xterm

I'm running two levels of xterms. In the first level I run "xterm -e bsub -Ip master.tcl". The master.tcl script invokes yet another xterm with "xterm -e bsub -Ip slave.tcl".

From some reason, when slave.tcl finishes executing, the second xterm is not closing. However, the second xterm does display the following message once the slave script finishes:
<< JobExitInfo: Job <128309> is done successfully. >>

Also, when looking at the LSF system, the job does not appear, as if it really finished. But the xterm window stays open, instead of closing.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that xterm would stay open unless there was something still running there.

I'd check (using ps -ef for instance) to see what processes are still running in the remaining xterm. xterm would only be still open if there were something running, e.g., waiting for input.

Using `ps -ef` (assuming this is not a BSD system), you would see a listing with a heading like this:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

and later in the listing, the relevant information, e.g.,

```
tom       3647 20185  0 06:17 pts/2    00:00:00 sh -c xterm -e vile 
tom       3648  3647  0 06:17 pts/2    00:00:00 xterm -e vile 
tom       3649  3648  0 06:17 pts/3    00:00:00 vile 
tom       3650  3649  0 06:17 pts/3    00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef 
tom       3651  3650  0 06:17 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

xterm's process-id (`PID`) is the place to start.  It would be found in the `PPID` (parent's process-ID) column at least one other place.  In turn, that process's `PID` may be used in further child-processes.

BSD systems use a different set of options (see [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Red%20Hat%20Linux%2Fi386%209&format=html) for example), but in general you can obtain the necessary information from `ps`.